# Number formatting with log10 scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, number-formatting, logarithm

I transformed the axis number to the log scale, but I also wanted to set number accuracy (decimal places) and decimal marks (dot or comma). My code is reproducible as follows.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=disp))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = log_trans(),
                            breaks = trans_breaks("log", function(x) exp(x), n.breaks = 5),
                            labels = trans_format("log", math_format(e^.x)))
```

Note that decimal places and marks of x-axis cannot be configured.

I tried to add a second scale_x_continuous with the wanted configurations, but it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `format` argument of `math_format` to change the number of decimals like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=disp))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = log_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log", function(x) exp(x), n.breaks = 5),
                     labels = trans_format("log", math_format(e^.x, format = function(x) number(x, accuracy = 0.1))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ok thanks. I noted that the same could be done with decimal marks.
Problem solved! Thanks again!